# Stop with the Sex Ads on SE sites, ESPECIALLY sites like "The Workplace"

Tags: bug, advertising, inappropriate-advertisements

I mean come on guys... this post should not even need a body. Are you asleep at the wheel? You tried show me "targeted ads"? Wow, way to fail. That must be a *joke*. You are showing me **completely unrelated random junk**!

- A sex shop.
- A "cool" shop (whatever that is)
- And a site for nutrition supplements (yeah, looks trustworthy... not)

[image]

Listen, I'm not prude and I don't object to be shown that kind of ad if I open random junk ad infested sites at home, but on "The Workplace" at SE? I would like to not filter out your ads, but you seem to really want me to.

Comment: Unfortunately, very related and almost a dup: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334515/176034

Comment: Also related: [Please give us an easy way to flag inappropriate ads](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/329700) Apparently the method I advocate in my answer is found to be ineffective.

Comment: On the plus side you have to hand it to the ad generator .. what would happen if you were to visit each of these in order? Or, maybe in _reverse_ order.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. This will be removed from our sites immediately.  Additionally, we are working really hard to block all inappropriate ads and provide you with reporting and ad customization tool.  Again thanks for reporting this ad.

Comment: Oh so [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329700/398063) is on its way? Do you have a rough estimate of when it will be available?

Comment: okay, I have to ask - what kind of system are you using? Because your system keeps failing over and over on a network that serves millions of people per day - that isn't good.

Comment: Why are you using a system at all?  Surely your ad traffic isn't so extensive that these ads couldn't be vetted by a real, live human being?

Comment: Terry, until is fixed I am using an ad blocker  on all SE sites. I could live with the ads itself, however, an accidental click on that add could get me into serious problems.