# Are ads supposed to be related with the site I'm on?

Tags: support, advertising

I was browsing on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) when this ad came up:

[image]

Is this type of ad allowed on a website that's not related at all to trips? I do have an account on Travel.SE but that's all.

Comment: Anything goes as long as it isn't NSFW

Comment: @Vishwa I do use an ad-blocker at home, not at my work computer but it might change, the ad experience is degrading over time.

Comment: @CaldeiraG unless at work you aren't allowed to install an adblocker, I find very little reason to go without one. Well, perhaps if your work is related to adverts could be another reason.

Comment: I'll stop using the Internet the day it won't be possible to block ads.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently it doesn't appear to matter given the state of the ads in place. Anything and pretty much everything, barring porn, seems to be displayed anywhere. That said there does appear to be hope in the future as Terry Guyton-Bradley, a staff member, has repeated they are developing a tool to customise the ad experience. What exactly this is, isn't clear but it sounds like it will mean ads will be targeted better. Whether that's on a site or user level I don't know.

> @Robotnik we are developing a tool that will give you control of the ad experience. I dont have a specific date of release, but we are working hard to get it out ASAP.
>
> <sub>[Arqade, comment](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14644/how-can-i-report-nsfw-ad-on-main-site#comment43969_14645)</sub>

> Thanks for reporting this. This will be removed from our sites immediately. Additionally, we are working really hard to block all inappropriate ads and provide you with reporting and ad customization tool. Again thanks for reporting this ad.
>
> <sub>[Stop with the Sex Ads on SE sites, ESPECIALLY sites like “The Workplace”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334537/stop-with-the-sex-ads-on-se-sites-especially-sites-like-the-workplace/334543#334543)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

If whatever algorithm happens to think that *you* might be interested in trips (which could be purely random for all I know), I suppose it's fair game.  Having it be related to the page you're on could be a bit constraining as there might not be that many products or services related to Linux's dynamic linker or a question about the acceptability of split infinitives in English.

In the end, it's just someone paying to reach someone who might be interested in what they're selling without wasting money on people who aren't.