# Today's inappropriate ad: health scam on Travel

Tags: support, advertising, inappropriate-advertisements

Inappropriate ad spotted on Travel.SE. Looks like the usual health scam. Unfortunately this one seems not to open the link preview when I long-click it, so it's only the image, but [it seems to have sufficed in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334537/398063).

> [image: lungs displaying scam ad]

Comment: Yeah I'm aware that "a tool to manage ad experience" is currently being developed, but as long as it's not available, I'll keep on reporting these. I'll also keep on intentionally refreshing until I get an inappropriate ad to report, because I find it to be a useful way to vent. Constructive I don't know, but useful I think so.

Comment: The ad is for an healthy community ...

Comment: @Jenayah make sure to use [TrackThis](https://trackthis.link/) to get different types of adverts.

Comment: Jenayah, getting 10k on MSE just by seeing inappropriate ads and reporting them.

Comment: @Randal'Thor oof, I hope the ads flag will be available way before that... Funny metric to gauge the number of inappropriate ads, though.

Comment: Eh, until folks realise the damage its doing to the brand, its something that we need to do. Not everyone who sees those ads is going to be a network regular after all.

Comment: @Randal'Thor plot twist: me and [Terry Guyton Bradley](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/576461/terry-guyton-bradley) (who should pop in anytime now to tell us that thank you for reporting, it has been taken off the list) are actually part of a sophisticated voting ring based on ad reporting/ad nuking. </joke>

Comment: @rene: The ad is mindless clickbait, the sort of trash one would find on any number of tabloid or celebrity sites.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm confused. Is that an argument for the ad being on the correct site ;)

Comment: 'nother day, 'nother ad. SE just keeps on giving.

Comment: Thank you for this. It is exactly what I was afraid of, just on a different site.

Comment: Dang, it’s like they’re using Taboola or Outbrain these are so bad...

Comment: @Stormblessed: That thought fills me with terror.

Comment: thanks for this. Looks like a serious health scam.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this problem can no longer be reproduced since the network advertising test has since ended.

Comment: This is now "solved" with the launch of the [Report this Ad Feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345476/report-this-ad-feature)