# Today​'s inappropriate ad: "obesity antidote discovered" on SFF

Tags: support, advertising, inappropriate-advertisements

Two days ago, [I wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335150/todays-inappropriate-ad-health-scam-on-travel#comment1100637_335150):

> Yeah I'm aware that "a tool to manage ad experience" is currently being developed, but as long as it's not available, I'll keep on reporting these. I'll also keep on intentionally refreshing until I get an inappropriate ad to report, because I find it to be a useful way to vent. Constructive I don't know, but useful I think so.

So without further ado, here's today's inappropriate ad: get rid of bulges in two hours only! On the other hand it was spotted on SFF, so maybe it's an elaborate ad for a magic school. Or maybe not.

> [image: Three roundish pink... things? Honestly I don't know what they are, but apparently they cure obesity.]

```
https://track.adform.net/C/?bn=30650830;atrid=47B6DF44BCF33015357995F69B8CF78397A50983;crtbwp=B9A7BD2BF125DC97;crtbdata=OiAcsqbnAswrFZQqCR_kZ2Wn4JePR2zFCAAU1mJ0vGivhSMTgLycNzV4jel9ZO3tjECZZRWHJUDNbzbLOYUh11URW10tZ9dYsW6sYswsr5CTA9-KKKFgbhsEV1hl0IypikSyMY6XAlyTmskCuGIRQAwr77pHR56HJOJOQQUg4yb5moMtlFHXzrOJ9pp7lRdQ2Ic140a9jKPJIwJYEOpk6qdnlVyBocSjK0m1DPoTJrfnkLdy4Thteekc645Jncc7CfWMxwjgXXvytcpFAVyai6D9Nf2YT7XEwLFe0_X_S15G5mAm1-RI1iObJFrglK4QCcVMB4DuDyXESLh3yCZgsLUHdrUWWsUcpTDT4IZcur1bWsEMfR0oQYTYiOG-OOG0uGDb_-D4szRcykHvktY-JemlY1w9wUp4cin7MiEyGTLFqOKz8y3FHeL5xHuazNZ3m7qNx144erx5pyyLHYUrRdVWQVq6P_baoPIIdQGfQ86Dn5h-6p-8ZuH3SNonk9sauoYs7_wF5FISqHBhWry2qUclsMDvZFx84UFuhV40q881;cset=fr-FR%7Cfr-FR%7C360X640%7C0%7C300%7C250%7C24%7C1%7C3%7C7%7C1%7C;cdata=6efWlRBYxHpNkoim8y32RgwRZGuFuL6pEx14g_hcwfpYBRXMc3-0AkKr1ztCzqheMrfXzzOMYt4RjUiKu9kvKNd2c2gTfv6XGGPGqNKy-9xEz2bcZzJe4tyR4UHah-JSIgE6IDlPshzGR6zwmEeX7Et5xTt2Y7rkjgNkToonbz2BIVblQGL2CV1wB9dfphhpwfNYnyIbkgnePS3pYtsRWg2;;gdpr=1;gdpr_consent=BOoY-JyOoY-Jy__AAA__Co-AAAAndIfafYrCwoWA3PZ5NgBgEK6BgQCFQAAACAAMYAIABQAACAUkgBEgiUAIAIBAAABARIJCAAgQAAASgAOAAAAAAgAAAAAAAABAAAEAAAAAABA;cpdir=
```

Comment: I am going to be amused if you got 10k off these

Comment: Don't forget to recharge your battery!

Comment: Rep farming 101. I've got to try it. Side note, I've come to like this series, can't wait to see what the next installment brings.

Comment: @Script47 If SE keeps allowing those sort of ads coming in, a will just applause anyone farming rep by denouncing that.

Comment: Surely the EU has a law about false medical claims and an appropriate official who accepts complaints....

Comment: @JourneymanGeek How do you think **I recently reached 10k??** I must have gained at least 3k rep at the end of June "thanks" to this incident.

Comment: And for full disclosure, I have just upvoted all four Jenayah inappropriate ads reports.

Comment: This sounds like quite the fun past time. any tips on how we can join the hunt?

Comment: @remy_rm _" I'll also keep on intentionally refreshing until I get an inappropriate ad to report [...]"_... Usually takes between 1 and 3 minutes of browsing random questions. Note that ads aren't enabled on all sites and they're partially hidden above a certain rep threshold. I guess incognito browsing also helps as ads are more likely to be random/not customised-for-you-only. Welcome to the team!

Comment: Seems very apt on a fantasy site, if you ask me.

Comment: When I tested ads on 5 sites using the *refresh* method, 21/25 autostarted with video in Chrome (intentionally used instead of Firefox). None were inappropriate. Glad to see you continuing to report the inappropriate appearances.

Comment: I like this investigative reporting quite a bit. I've gone from heartsick to amused, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 8):

Thank you for reporting. We can't flag these ads as "rude or abusive" so you have to blame SE for their ads quality degradation. During your patient waiting for SE to handle this, we recommend handy gadgets like uBlock Origin or AdBlock Plus for you to ensure high-quality browsing experience on Stack Exchange. It's been a must-have since the recent dismissal of their "no animated ads" policy!

Comment: Some of us use browsers on which we can't install an ad blocker.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica Some of us are in company/education environments where you can't configure DNS settings.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica Which would lead to complaints from users who try to access websites that block ad-blocker users from using them. (FYI my browser does support extensions, and I'm using one that not only blocks ads but also bypasses anti-adblock measures.)

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica It's called [Nano Defender](https://jspenguin2017.github.io/uBlockProtector). It works with uBlock Origin, but it requires a lot of configuration steps, so the author has released a forked version called Nano Adblocker that has those configuration steps already in place.